# No puedo actualizar los datos de una tabla en SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql, update

Intentare ser lo mas especifico posible.

Mi tabla en SQL Server `<OrdenesDeCompra>` aloja información sobre ordenes de compra, un conjunto de productos y otros datos la conforman, de vez en cuando es necesario realizar una actualización de la misma (cambiando el nombre del producto a causa de un mal tipeo, su cantidad, etc).

Lo que hice fue crear una tabla(1) donde se consulten todas las ordenes de compra creadas con sus respectivos items esta vista la tiene gracias a un `DataGridView`, cuando el usuario clickea en alguno de los items un apartado(2) dentro del form le copia todos los datos a editar en distintos `TextBoxs`, el usuario puede hacerle cambios a esos textboxs y tocando en el botón "Aceptar" estos teóricamente deberían actualizarse(3) en la base de datos y digo teóricamente porque es ahí donde empieza mi problema.

Adjuntaré los siguientes códigos que son los que componen toda la ruta que hace el proceso.

Aquí paso los valores del datagridview(1) a los textboxs (2)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = eodcdt.CurrentRow;
    eilblnumerodeorden.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    eilblnumeroitem.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    eirazonsocial.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(); 
    eiproducto.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(); 
    eicantidad.Text = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    eipreciounitario.Text = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
    eiacreditacion.Text = row.Cells[16].Value.ToString(); 
    eilugardeentrega.Text = row.Cells[13].Value.ToString(); 
    eifechadeentrega.Text = row.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
    eiformadepago.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    DataTable dt = Program.LlenarComboBoxProveedores();
    eirazonsocial.DataSource = dt;
    eirazonsocial.ValueMember = "RazonSocial";
    eirazonsocial.DisplayMember = "RazonSocial";
    Program.RazonSocial = eirazonsocial.Text;
    Program.ProveedorData();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando se toca el botón "Aceptar" los valores de los `textbox` actualizan la información según el número de item Ej : 1000-1

Cuando hago pausas en el código para ver si los valores se están guardando en las variables efectivamente lo hace, el `Ex.Message` nunca se activó y siempre termina mostrándome el `MessageBox` sobre que los datos se actualizaron osea que el `NonQuery` se ejecuta con éxito me imagino.

Una vez que pasa esto consulto con la base de datos si los mismos fueron actualizados y me encuentro con la sorpresa que eso no pasa. No puedo encontrar la falla que este provocando que los valores no se actualicen.

```
public static void UpdateEditarOrdenDeCompra()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conexion);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("Update OrdenesDeCompra set producto= @producto, cantidad=@cantidad, preciounitario=@preciounitario, formadepago=@formadepago, fechadeentrega=@fechadeentrega, lugardeentrega=@lugardeentrega, acreditacion=@acreditacion where ordendecompra=@ordendecompra", con);

        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrdenDeCompra", einumerodeordenitem);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", eiproducto);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", eicantidad);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioUnitario", eipreciounitario);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormaDePago", eiformadepago);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDeEntrega", eifechadeentrega);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LugarDeEntrega", eilugardeentrega);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acreditacion", eiacreditacion);


        consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Valores editados.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)    
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Esquema de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es un poco complicado ayudarte, entre otras cosas necesitaríamos ver la definición de la tabla `OrdenesDeCompra`, pero asi a priori me rechina un poco un campo que se llama `Fecha` y al que le estás pasando un string. De que tipo es `fechadeentrega` en tu tabla?

Comment: Aprovecho para darte la bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: No se como ingresar imagenes en comentarios, acabo de tomar una foto de la tabla de la base de datos. https://i.ibb.co/VtfdkYC/task2.png
Todos los items son de tipo VarChar50 
El campo fecha lo que hace es agregar en que momento se crea la Orden de compra, te explico. A veces las ordenes de compra son para cosas que van a comprar dentro de 15 o 20 dias pero ya la dejan preparada de esta forma le ponen una fecha posterior a la del dia de la fecha y por otro lado hago un control de que dia se creo realmente esa orden en el campo FechaDeCreacion

Espero haber sido lo mas claro posible.

Comment: validaste que te conectas a la base de datos correcta ? no se si es una db local o en algun servidor, pero valida el connection string si apunta a la db que luego validas si actualizo

Comment: la db esta integrada en el Visual Studio, o sea puedes ver el .mdf en el solution explorer ? o es una db que esta bajo el servicio de sql server y la administrs con el Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: La conexion es la correcta de echo uso la misma conexion para consultar en el datagridview, el Sql server lo administro en Sql server managment Studio desde otro pc.

Comment: Es bastante raro la verdad. Espero solucionarlo pronto de todas formas agradezco mucho el esfuerzo. 

Gracias por la bienvenida y por la edición del post para una mejor claridad.

Saludos!

Comment: Se me ocurre algo. El `Where` no se debe estar cumpliendo, fijate que `einumerodeordenitem` no contenga espacios que puedan estar haciendo que no coincida con lo que hay en tu tabla (prueba por ejemplo `consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrdenDeCompra", einumerodeordenitem.Trim());`. También probaría a poner los nombres de parámetros en minúsculas para que coincidan exactamente con como lo tienes en tu query de update

Comment: Encontre el problema, en mi tabla sql uso dos indices uno para conocer el grupo osea la orden de compra completa Ej: 1000 y una segunda columna para conocer el numero del item Ej: 1000-1 Lo que hacia era buscar 1000-1 en la columna donde solo marco el numero de orden (1000). el tema esta resuelto. Muchísimas gracias nuevamente por la ayuda brindada Pikoh.

Comment: por indices te refieres a que tienes dos primery key en la tabla ? si es asi esta claro que para localizar un registro unico deberas aplicar en el WHERE ambas columnas

Comment: No no, por indices me refiero a que dependiento el cambio es el dato que voy a tomar como criterio de busqueda, si cambia el proveedor debera cambiar para toda la orden (1000), si cambia el producto cambiara solo el nombre del item (1000-3)

Comment: Por favor, la información relevante, en lo posible, se incluye como texto. Va para la estructura de la tabla y demás info que la gente puede usar para replicar el problema. Diferente a, digamos, la interfaz de usuario,

Answer (score 1):

La función ExecuteNonQuery devuelve el número de filas afectadas. Verifica que número te devuelve despues de que se ejecuta.

[documentación ExecuteNonQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery)

Otra opción es utilizar la herramienta SQL Server Profiler; así puedes ver las transaciones que realiza tu aplicación y encontrar el motivo por el cual no se actualiza la información.

Puedes acceder al SQL Server Profiler atraves del menú Herramientas/Sql Server Profile

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero verifique que los datos que llegan de los textbox este correctos en relación al tipo de dato esperado en la base de datos. A mi me estuvo pasando esto y es porque el executenonQuery no era necesario invocarlo. El que se necesita invocar es el ExecuteReader.

```
public static void UpdateEditarOrdenDeCompra()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conexion);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("Update OrdenesDeCompra set producto= @producto, cantidad=@cantidad, preciounitario=@preciounitario, formadepago=@formadepago, fechadeentrega=@fechadeentrega, lugardeentrega=@lugardeentrega, acreditacion=@acreditacion where ordendecompra=@ordendecompra", con);

        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrdenDeCompra", einumerodeordenitem);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", eiproducto);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", eicantidad);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioUnitario", eipreciounitario);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormaDePago", eiformadepago);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDeEntrega", eifechadeentrega);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LugarDeEntrega", eilugardeentrega);
        consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acreditacion", eiacreditacion);


        var reader=consulta.ExecuteReader();

        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Valores editados.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)    
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si es que ambos metodos estan en la misma clase y los parametros de los AddWithValue son los textBox , se los estarías pasando mal ,ya que estas pasando los objetos texbox y no sus valores. Debería quedar así:

```
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrdenDeCompra", eilblnumerodeorden.Text);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", eiproducto.Text);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", eicantidad.Text);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioUnitario", eipreciounitario.Text);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormaDePago", eiformadepago.Text);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDeEntrega", eifechadeentrega.Text);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LugarDeEntrega", eilugardeentrega.Text);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acreditacion", eiacreditacion.Text);


    consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Valores editados.");
```

### Ojo por los tipos de datos.

No te da error por que los objetos se les toma el Casting Implicito a String por que intentas actualizar donde el IDAcreditacion sea "Windows.Form.TextBox" o algo similar ya que estas pasando toda la caja(textbox) en vez de su valor (textbox.Text)